# 80's/90's cartoon about three characters who gain powers by absorbing a card into their chest

Tags: story-identification

I have been searching like a madmen the past few days but can't find anything. Maybe one of you guys knows what this is.

- I remember one lady/girl often stuck or traveling in some pod/capsule.
- There were three characters that gained/activated their power by absorbing some kind of card into their chest. (Humanoid)
- I believe they fused at some point into a golden warrior of some sort for a fight. (at the end of which they were cut/wounded and energy/light started to flow out of them, Was humanoid)

I know this is very vague and I hope someone remembers this show. Maybe even a movie for all I know.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Warrior_Gold_Lightan

Comment: Chest powers makes me think of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visionaries:_Knights_of_the_Magical_Light but I don't think they ever fused together.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!_Duel_Monsters = Magic cards and putting crap into people's chests

Comment: They are simular to what i've described but they are not the one i mean D: Sorry there is so little information to go on about. I'll edit the post if i remember more bits. Like the main chars where al humanoid.

Comment: AHHH! I found it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinzo Thanks to a suggestion of a friend i've found it. Thanks for the suggestions guys.

Comment: @Zenros If you return, come back and add it as a full answer.  Self-answers are okay, and you did find the answer yourself, so nobody else is likely to come along and write in the answer.  Better you fill it in, and you'll also get a badge for it.

Answer (score 4):

As the OP has stated in a comment, this is the anime series [*Shinzo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinzo) by Tetsuo Imazawa.

> In the series, genetically-altered creatures known as Enterrans take over Earth and rename it in their own image called Enterra. Now three Enterrans have to protect the last human in order to find the hidden sanctuary called Shinzo and restore the human race. The anime focuses primarily on the adventures they undergo while working to accomplish this task.

In the first season, it is identified (Emphasis mine):

> Mushra, Sago. and Kutal are then shown to be Hyper-Enterrans, Enterrans who can transform into stronger powered-up versions of themselves, these forms allow them to fight the various creatures that come after them. Throughout the first season the main characters fight a collection of Enterrans known as the Seven Enterran Generals, and various independent Enterrans where these Enterrans were either minions of the Seven Enterran Generals or bounty hunters. Each of these Generals rules a region that the gang travels through, which have different types of Enterrans, such as King Daku's land having a majority insect based Enterrans. ***The defeated Enterrans become En-Cards, which are card-like structures that can be used to increase power in both Enterrans and several machines such as Yakumo's vehicle Hakuba.***